# Overriding View action of Objects inside napili community

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, napili, lightning-community

By default in Salesforce Classic, Salesforce offers to override the standard action buttons of Salesforce objects.

Ex:view, edit buttons.

The overridden functions are working fine inside lightning experience, but they have no impact inside napili community.

For that in the new release Salesforce has given an option to override the standard actions using lightning component also Visualforce pages for Salesforce classic & lightning experience and lightning components for lightning.

When I tried to override the standard action buttons using lightning components the buttons become invisible within the napili community, whereas the "view" action is perfoming its default behaviour.

Can anyone suggest how to override standard action buttons for objects inside napili community?

Comment: Do you have forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes implemented for the component that you are using on community?